# How to detect unsaved data in form when user leaves the page?

Tags: jsf

I need to detect unsaved data in form when user leaves the page without submitting the form. I would like to implement that without adding a value change listener to each input.

This is the functional requirement:

> "User open a page than click on any link if values in the page changed an alert message popup to notify user that he need to save changed data, but if did not change any thing system continue without notify user".

I tried to compare array method to compare both DTO coming for DB and the bind DTO, but it gives me a lot of problems in array length, and byte comparison.

Comment: @JasperdeVries: I duped it the other way round, because current one has 12k views and other one 3k. Apparently better search keywords here.

Answer (score 19):

This is normally implemented in the client side with help of JavaScript, because it's not nicely possible to intercept on `beforeunload` event from the server side on when the enduser leaves the page.

Here's a concrete example with help of the JavaScript library [jQuery](http://jquery.com) (otherwise you would end up with 10 times as much code to make it properly crossbrowser compatible and work seamlessly together with ajax re-renders):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        // Set the unload message whenever any input element get changed.
        $(':input').on('change', function() {
            setConfirmUnload(true);
        });

        // Turn off the unload message whenever a form get submitted properly.
        $('form').on('submit', function() {
            setConfirmUnload(false);
        });
    });

    function setConfirmUnload(on) {
        var message = "You have unsaved data. Are you sure to leave the page?";
        window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? function() { return message; } : null;
    }
</script>
```

Just paste this in your `<h:head>` template or just put it in some `script.js` file which you include by `<h:outputScript>`.

Comment: Thank you , for your reply but Jquery script has the following problems ----------- $(':input').on('change', function() ---- is not a function , I changed it to by as the following ---------------$(':input').change(function() in both calling handlers, I would like to ask why the server side solution is not good , plus how can I change the message to be a custom message. thank you very much

Comment: You're using an outdated version of jQuery. Either upgrade jQuery to latest, or use `.live()` instead of `.on()`. The `.change()` won't work properly if you're using JSF ajax to update fields. The server side solution is overcomplicated and nearly impossible to implement to cover all possible client behaviours. Changing the message is easy, just edit the `var message`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
$(function() {
            // Set the unload message whenever any input element get changed.
            $('input').change(function() {
                setConfirmUnload(true);
            });

            // Turn off the unload message whenever a form get submitted properly.
            $('form').submit(function() {
                setConfirmUnload(false);
            });
        });

        function setConfirmUnload(on) {
            var message = "You have unsaved data. Are you sure to leave the page?";
            window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? function() { return message; } : null;
        }
```