# ios javascript pagehide and unload doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I would like display a popup when the user close tab or refresh page on ios to prevent him he will lose his datas. I have seen `unload` is deprecated and I have to use `pagehide` event but it seems the both don't work on safari and even chrome.

My code is:

```
window.addEventListener("pagehide", function (evt) {
    return confirm("Vous allez perdre toutes vos modifications");
}, false);
```

The problem is the page refresh even if I click on cancel button, and the popup doesn't appear if I close the tab.

i tried this code too for Chrome mobile (desktop work fine) but the both don't work with his browser

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    if (closeWindow) {
        var message = 'Toutes vos modifications seront perdues';
        if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
            evt = window.event;
        }
        if (evt) {
            evt.returnValue = message;
        }
        return message;
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Did you positively try to interact with the page before testing? There are indications that some browser implementations require user interaction with the page (whatever that means) before honoring the prompt in pagehide/beforeunload.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `unload` fires too late to pop up a message. You can sometimes get around this by using `beforeunload`, but it is not implemented in iOS Safari. :( Perhaps you can do something tricky with sending off an AJAX request to the server on `unload` (see: [How to detect unsaved data in form when user leaves the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259090/how-to-detect-unsaved-data-in-form-when-user-leaves-the-page)).

I'm not sure it'll help, but you could also think about automatically saving the user's data on `unload` by saving it to `localstorage` or sending it to your server.

Comment: Fun fact: as of checking today, [caniuse.com says](https://caniuse.com/#search=beforeunload) the `beforeunload` event is supported by all browsers. However, as you've mentioned, I've confirmed in my case that `beforeunload` does not work on iOS 12.