# detectUnsavedChanges on dialogReturn event

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my view I have a disabled `p:inputText` showing some adress information. The value of the `p:inputText` is set by the `dialogReturn` listener `onAdresseDialogReturn()`. Besides this inputText I have several other input fields (`p:selectOneMenu`, `p:inputText`).

Whenever I change some values of the other input components and try to leave the page, I get a warning dialog from the `detectUnsavedChanges` JavaScript.

My problem now is, that I want this warning message also, when the `dialogReturn` listener changes the value of the inputText field - but this does not happen!

So my question is, how can I achieve this?

Here the `p:inputText` with a `p:commandButton` using the primefaces dialog framework:

```
<ui:composition>

    <ui:define name="head">
        <h:outputScript name="js/detectUnsavedChanges.js"/>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:panelGrid>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandButton id="save" value="Save" ajax="false" action="#{bean.save}"/>
                    </p:columns>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>

            <p:panelGrid>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputText id="adresse" disabled="true" size="50"
                                     value="#{bean.adresse}"/>
                        <p:commandButton id="adresseAuswahl" 
                                         title="Adresse bearbeiten"
                                         process="@this"
                                         actionListener="#{bean.showAdresseDialog}">
                            <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update="adresse"
                                    listener="#{bean.onAdresseDialogReturn}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>  
                    </p:columns>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Here the `dialogReturn` listener in my bean:

```
public void onAdresseDialogReturn(SelectEvent e) {
    final Adresse adresse = (Adresse) e.getObject();
    boolean changedAdresse = Optional.ofNullable(adresse).isPresent() 
            && !getAdresse().equals(adresse);
    if (changedBauvorhabenAdresse) {
        // Adresse has been changed
        setAdresse(adresse);
    }
}
```

Here the JavaScript code as mentioned by BalusC from [How to detect unsaved data in form when user leaves the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259090/how-to-detect-unsaved-data-in-form-when-user-leaves-the-page):

```
$(function() {
    // Set the unload message whenever any input element get changed.
    $(':input').on('change', function() {
        setConfirmUnload(true);
    });

    // Turn off the unload message whenever a form get submitted properly.
    $('form').on('submit', function() {
        setConfirmUnload(false);
    });
});

function setConfirmUnload(on) {
    var message = "You have unsaved data. Are you sure to leave the page?";
    window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? function() { return message; } : null;
}
```

My Environment: Primefaces 6.0 on Wildfly-10.0.0.Final

Any hints welcome - Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an `oncomplete` attribute to your `p:ajax` inside the `commandButton`.
I don't actually know if you can put a `p:ajax` component inside the `p:commandButton` however in the oncomplete attribute you should call setConfirmUnload(true) like this:

```
                   <p:commandButton id="adresseAuswahl" 
                                     title="Adresse bearbeiten"
                                     process="@this"
                                     actionListener="#{bean.showAdresseDialog}">
                        <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update="adresse"
                                listener="#{bean.onAdresseDialogReturn}" oncomplete="setConfirmUnload(true)"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: The `p:commandButton` is already ajaxified by default as mentioned in the PrimeFaces showcase and documentation

Comment: I thought so. I'd use the `p:ajax` component inside the `dialog` component listening to the **close** event. Like this: 
      `<p:dialog>
          <p:ajax event="close" update="adresse"
                                listener="#{bean.onAdresseDialogReturn}" oncomplete="setConfirmUnload(true)"/>
       </p:dialog>`

Comment: But now the confirm dialog appears always - even if `changedBauvorhabenAdresse` is false in my `onAdresseDialogReturn()` listener. I tried `oncomplete="setConfirmUnload(#{bean.changedBauvorhabenAdresse})"` but the getter of `changedBauvorhabenAdresse` is called only once during page creation and not when the ajax event occurs! How can I solve this?

Comment: yes it's called only once when JSF is creating your HTML page and evaulating client-side attributes of the components used.

Comment: It should be reevaluated on every update of the `p:commandButton` component though.

Comment: changing `update="adresse adresseAuswahl"` in my ajax event tag does not re-evaluate the `p:commandButton` and therefore does not show the confirm dialog on page change?!

Comment: @raho When is it that you want to call your javascript method?

Comment: the javascript method should be called after the dialogReturn listener and should use as parameter a value which is set be the listener

Comment: Try debugging and see if it actually calls the method `isChangedBauvorhabenAdress‌​e` in your bean.

Comment: adding the id of the button to ajax update (`update="adresse adresseAuswahl"`) re-evaluates `changedBauvorhabenAdresse` and die confirm dialog appears as expected - thank you!